# fill data in excel by key: value using formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that contains rows:

```
A1 = Typical
A2 = Typical
A3 = Expressed
A4 = Expressed
A5 = 3600
A6 = Typical
```

Where Typical is equal to 3800 and Expressed is 5000

I tried setting D4 = Typical, E4 = 3800 and D5 = Expressed while E5 = 5000 as my key:value cells. I then tried something like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D4,A1)), E4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D5,A1)), E5,A1))
```

Is there a way to make this formula variables for D4, E4, D5, E5 "stick" while A1 can be replaced with A2-A6?

I am expecting a result where B1-B6 is like so:

```
B1 = 3800
B2 = 3800
B3 = 5000
B4 = 5000
B5 = 3600
B6 = 3800
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$D$4:$E$5,2,False),A1)`  Put in B1 and Copy down.

Comment: This is the only solution here. Vlookup allows for exact matches, whereas Lookup will return closest matches, and Gary's Student assumes that there are only 2 values.

Comment: These are great. I really do have only two values at the moment, but your answers are equally valuable. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,IF(A1=$D$4,$E$4,$E$5))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! Thank you for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like: (in B1 and copy down)

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(A1,$D$4:$D$5,$E$4:$E$5),A1)
```